# Reproducing the style of Stacks Project \TeX documents

Tags: fonts, fontsize

For my work, I use a lot the Stacks Project documents printed in PDF. I am trying to use the same style (especially text fonts and size of them) because I am used to it for my own documents but it seems that using lmodern fonts and 10 or 11 pt does not give exactly the same results.

Can anybody give me precise indications about which main options I have to use in my preamble ? I looked into their own preamble but it points to a stackproject.cls a bit difficult for me to analyse.

Comment: @R.Schumacher thank you for your time ! Actually I just want to know the font and font size use for the normal paragraph text (not the math fonts) as it appears in the pdf. I cannot use an external non standard .cls in my preamble (your Q1) and the font package amsfonts is installed in my texlive distribution but if I use it will it change also the text fonts ?

Comment: @R.Schumacher I am afraid you are right. Will do it tomorrow ...

Comment: @R.Schumacher BTW, I did a test run using their stacks-project.cls dedicated class. Nothing changed. I am afraid it has something to do with the way the PDF engine works (or even my printer ?) : I am using pdflatex with TeXshop on OS X.

Comment: Try loading your MWE and the stacks-project.cls up to Overleaf and try the compile there and view their generated PDF.  Do this before you modify you TeX setup.

Comment: @R.Schumacher Thanks to your advice I found the solution to my problem: The design of the CM text fonts is slightly different between 11pt and 10 pt. I was using 10 pt, so I changed to 11pt and resize the paper with package geometry and now my papers look like stacks-project PDF. If you make one of your comment an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick scan or the '*.cls' files for both the book and the project so that the base text font is computer modern (default font) and the math font is from the current amsfonts package. Then there are many (>30) size and style modifications defined in the cls file.

1) Why not just use the 'stackproject.cls' file.

2) You can otherwise start with a font change to amsfont. You may need to install the font so go here for instructions http://tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html.

3) I went out the the Stack Project and looked at the pdf file and it is Computer Modern, so build a test file and try different font sizes to get their look.

Comment: the `amsfonts` package only adds symbols for use in math; it makes no changes or additions to text fonts.  therefore, those must be established somewhere else.  `amsfonts` is part of any tex live installation, so i would definitley *not* suggest undertaking the installation of anything per your #2.  where exactly can one find `stackproject.cls`?  (i can probably easily identify the default font and likely size by looking at the code.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for the catch.  Generally I should not debug after sundown:(